# Transform request in http config is changing scope

Tags: angularjs

I need to transform data before I send it to an API.
This is done in `TransformRequest` is the `config` passed into `$http`.

The problem is that changes made inside `TransformRequest` are also applied in the scope in my view.

Here is a simple **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l7OGmHjBkXbAYwOjkla6?p=preview)** so you can see it in action.

Note :

Those changes aren't applied to the view when `scope.test` is not an object.
Ex.: `scope.test = "2";` or `scope.test = 2;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the id of the same object that is used on the scope since that object is passed into the tranform method.
 You could create a copy of the object, modify the copy and return the modified copy from the transform mehthod:

```
 transformRequest : function(data){
    var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    copy.id = null;
    return copy;
 }
```

The example uses JSON de/serialization of course you coud also use other methods. Through the JSON de/serialization you create a completely new object which has the same content but otherwise has nothing in common with your original data object. This is done by converting the object into a JSON string wich holds the data and reconstructing a new object from that JSON string data.

If you use a non object like "2" this could not happen since "2" is only a string value and not an object reference.

Comment: `var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));` is working, but `var copy = data;` is still changing the scope. What is JSON doing to break the link between copy and data?

Comment: Thank you. Don't you think wathever you do in `TransformRequest` should not change the scope? This is the only purpose of this array of functions...

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THIS!

Note here is what I did

```transformRequest : function(data){
    var copy = {};
     angular.copy(data, copy);
    // NOW copy is a copy of data but not binded to it...aka you can change copy without affecting data
    return copy;
 }```